# Creating GitHub pull request from Android Studio gives error

Tags: git, android-studio, github, pull-request, http-status-code-422

I am attempting to create a pull request from Android Studio. I have edited a file, commited the file, and then when I click `Create pull request` it tries to create it and I receive the error below:

```
Can't Create Pull Request
Can't create pull request

422 Unprocessable Entity - Validation Failed
[PullRequest; null]custom: No commits between master and master
```

My branches and remotes are set up correctly as far as I know. I am able to directly push as well so I know it can access GitHub.

---

This is what the `Create pull request` menu looks like:

[image: This is what the <code>Create pull request</code> menu looks like]

---

This is what my `Git Remotes` menu looks like:
[image: This is what my <code>Git Remotes</code> menu looks like]

---

My questions is am I missing a step that I need to do before I create the pull request? If not, why am I receiving this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to this.

You need to create a new branch then push the commits to that branch then create the pull request that compares the newly created branch and the master branch.